# is it correct parameters for pgbouncer.ini and postgresql.conf?

Tags: postgresql

I have pgbouncer.ini file with the below configuration

```
[databases]
test_db = host=localhost port=5432 dbname=test_db 

[pgbouncer]
logfile = /var/log/postgresql/pgbouncer.log
pidfile = /var/run/postgresql/pgbouncer.pid
listen_addr = 0.0.0.0
listen_port = 5433
unix_socket_dir = /var/run/postgresql 
auth_type = md5
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/userlist.txt
admin_users = postgres

#pool_mode = transaction
pool_mode = session
server_reset_query = RESET ALL; 
ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits
max_client_conn = 25000
autodb_idle_timeout = 3600
default_pool_size = 250
max_db_connections = 250
max_user_connections = 250
```

and I have in my postgresql.conf file

```
max_connections = 2000
```

does it effect badly on the performance ? because of max_connections in my postgresql.conf ? or it doesn't mean anything and already the connection handled by the pgbouncer ?

one more question. in pgpouncer configuration, does it right listen_addr = 0.0.0.0 ? or should to be listen_addr = * ?

Is it better to set default_pool_size on PgBouncer equal to the number of CPU cores available on this server?

Shall all of default_pool_size, max_db_connections and max_user_connections to be set with the same value ?

Answer (score 2):

So the idea of using pgbouncer is to pool connections when you can't afford to have a higher number of max_connections in PG itself.
NOTE: Please DO NOT set max_connections to a number like 2000 just like that.

Let's start with an example, if you have a connection limit of 20 and then your app or organization wants to have a 1000 connections at a given time, that is where pooler comes into picture and in this specific case you want the 20 connections to pool that 1000 coming in from the application.

To understand how it actually works let's take a step back and understand what happens when you do not have a connection pooler and only rely on PG config setting for the max connections which in our case is 20.

So when a connection comes in from a client\application etc. the main process of postgresql(PID, i.e. parent ID) spawns a child for that. So each new connection spawns a child process under the main postgres process, like so:

```
PID USER      PR NI VIRT RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM TIME+  COMMAND             
24379 postgres  20 0 346m 148m 122m R 61.7  7.4 0:46.36 postgres: sysbench sysbench ::1(40120) 
24381 postgres  20 0 346m 143m 119m R 62.7  7.1 0:46.14 postgres: sysbench sysbench ::1(40124) 
24380 postgres  20 0 338m 137m 121m R 57.7  6.8 0:46.04 postgres: sysbench sysbench ::1(40122) 
24382 postgres  20 0 338m 129m 115m R 57.4  6.5 0:46.09 postgres: sysbench sysbench ::1(40126)
```

So now once a connection request is sent, it is received by the POSTMASTER process and creates a child process at OS level under the main parent process. This connection then has a life span of "unlimited" unless close by the application or you have a time out set for idle connections in postgresql.

Now here comes the situation where it can be a very costly affair to manage the connections with a given compute, if they exceed a certain limit. Meaning n number of connections when served have a given compute cost and after some time the OS won't be able to handle a situation with HUGE connections and will in turn cause contentions at different compute level(i.e. Memory, CPU, I/O).

What if you can use the presently spawned child processes(backends) if they are not doing any work. You will save time on getting the child process(backends) and the additional cost as well(this can be different at times). This is where the pool of connections that are always open help to serve different client requests comes in and is also called pooling.

So basically now you have only n connections available but the pooler can manage n+i number of connections to serve the client requests.

This where pg-bouncer helps to reuse the connections. It can be configured with 3 types of pooling i.e Session pooling, Statement pooling and Transaction pooling. Basically bouncer returns the connection back to the pool once it has done, statement level work or transaction level work etc. Only during session pooling it keeps the connections unless it disconnects.

So basically lower down the number of connections at PG conf file level and tune all settings in the bouncer.ini.

**To answer the second part:**

one more question. in pgpouncer configuration, does it right listen_addr = 0.0.0.0 ? or should to be **listen_addr = *** ?

It depends if you have a standalone deployment, server etc.
basically if its on the server itself and you want it to allow connections from everywhere(incoming) use `"*"` if you want only the local network to be allowed use `"127.0.0.0".`

For the rest of your questions check this link: [pgbouncer docs](https://www.pgbouncer.org/config.html)

I have tried to share a little of what I know, feel free to ask away if anything was unclear or or correct if it was incorrectly mentioned.

Comment: I totally agree with you regarding the point of   "So basically lower down the number of connections at PG conf file level and tune all settings in the bouncer.ini.".   But I just joined my company and I found these configurations already exist and having many tuning issues so I ask if "max_connections = 2000" in postgresql.conf making performance issue ? or this is doesn't mean any sense and already handled by pgbouncer ?

Comment: Is it better to set default_pool_size on PgBouncer equal to the number of CPU cores available on this server?

Shall all of default_pool_size, max_db_connections and max_user_connections to be set with the same value ?

Comment: i edited and added a link for the last question, but for max connections it will definitely have an impact cos each connections depending on the queries coming in will have an additional mem consumption depending upon what "work_mem" is set and then eventually it can also show CPU spikes along with I/O bottlenecks when you have parallel transaction processing happening.

Comment: Is it better to set default_pool_size on PgBouncer equal to the number of CPU cores available on this server?

Comment: Well there isn't a hard and fast rule but its definitely a good practice and there are reasons behind it which i do not want to get into right now. but yes you can set it equal to the number of cores available, doubling it to the number of cores also won't hurt unless you have like 50 or 100 cores.

Comment: I read your reply on my question regarding " in pgpouncer configuration, does it right listen_addr = 0.0.0.0 ? or should to be listen_addr = * ? "

but in my current case the listen_addr = 0.0.0.0 not "*", so this is correct parameter and the same as "*" ? or this is incorrect parameter and should to be "*" ?

Comment: Yeah its fine, it means it will listen to all the ip’s that the host has, basically a shell equivalent of “*”

Comment: I checked the link which you mentioned related to pgbouncer configuration but still didn't get the point about the same values for default_pool_size, max_db_connections and max_user_connections, is it fixed and always should be the same value for all of them ? because I saw many examples and putting the same value for all of those three

Comment: check this article to tune\set config settings:

https://www.compose.com/articles/how-to-pool-postgresql-connections-with-pgbouncer/

Comment: I already checked it before but still don't know how to calculate the three parameters' values. At my current case I have 1 database and for applications connected on it and many concurrent users ( more than 3000 ). so please can you please take my current situation as a example and explain it to me ?

Comment: well please don't take it otherwise but i believe you need to do some reading as everything is pretty nicely mentioned in there. I cannot just give you vague numbers it all depends on business case and different scenarios. I would say spend some time reading this, official docs of bouncer and then try some configs and do bench marking.

Comment: Okay I'll consider your advice and I'll read a lot and I'll try, but if you please accept my last question
max_db_connections means the maximum threads for every connection ? and max_user_connections means maximum connections for every user ?

Comment: In your case using session might not work for pgbouncer and you might have to switch to transaction as in session it will wait for the others to close before it can reuse the connection from the pool which can cause delays, but i do not know what kind of transaction numbers are you throwing at the server? How many cores do you have?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210101/discussion-between-eng-bassel-and-raj-verma).